# Passing by variable through an external library

Tags: c, pointers, parameter-passing

How do you perform pass by variable on an interface function provided by a C library?

For example, I have the following interface function:

`void f( double *d ) { *d = 7.5; }`

In my application, I link through that library and call the function:

`double p = 0;

f( &p );`

However, I noticed p is still 0 and not 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the prototype for `f` in scope, in your application?

If you haven't the compiler converts the address of `p` to an int; and if they aren't the same size or use the same passing conventions or whatever, you have problems.

You should `#include "the_proper_header.h"` or you may directly add the prototype in your application, right before you call the function.

```
double p = 0;
void f(double *);
f( &p );
```

Comment: Yes, the header file is already included. Is there any special handling if the function is not within the program but in another library? There are no linking errors.

Comment: No, no special handling. Many many functions (`printf`, `malloc`, `sqrt`, ..., ...) are not defined within the programs that use them. Are you really using plain old C? Your use of "interface" is strange(ish)

Comment: That's what I thought too. Yes, plain C, what makes it strange?

Comment: Thanks for confirming, anyway, I found the issue and it's not related to the above.

Comment: Re interface strangeness (possibly my misuse of English): to me, "interface" applies to library (or module) not specific functions. I'd probably just leave out the 1st "interface" from your question and replace the 2nd, in "interface function", with "function definition".

Comment: @jason: if you found the answer to your question, you may want to post (and accept) it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Your example worked, see http://codepad.org/JJL7eab5.

The only change I made was that I declared `f()` before defining it:

```
void f(double *);
```

It would also work if the function definition were declared as static. In C, functions need to be either declared before their definition or declared as static.

Comment: Yes, it works if just in an ordinary program. But when I tried to place f() in a library, I noticed it only passes the parameters by value even if I changed it inside the library.